# how can I verify a method was called n times?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm spying on a method of my component like this :

```
spyOn(component, 'someMethod');
```

How can I verify that component.someMethod was called n times ?

Intelisense is not giving me the `calls` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need any custom methods. Jasmine does provide method toHaveBeenCalledTimes()

See the jasmine doc.

https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html

for your example it will be -
expect(component.yourmethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(n);

Answer (score 1):

```
it("tracks the number of times it was called", function() {
    spyOn(foo, 'setBar');

    expect(foo.setBar.calls.count()).toEqual(0);

    foo.setBar();
    foo.setBar();

    expect(foo.setBar.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
```

Comment: Code only answers don't usually work on their own - please add an explanation as to how this helps solve the problem

Comment: This code is not working and also misleading... Working example: `const existsSyncSpy = jest.spyOn(fs, 'existsSync');` and then check via `expect(existsSyncSpy.mock.calls.length).toBeGreaterThan(8);`